# Code First to existing database - setting up a one to one relationship where TableA doesn't have an approprite foreign key reference to TableB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Ok, I have a strange situation while trying to map some POCO classes to a database that was not created by me.

Here is the setup of the tables.

```
TableA
(
    TableA_ID int primary key,
    // other fields
)

TableB
(
    TableB_ID int primary key,
    TableA_ID int unique not null,
    // other fields
)
```

So, how the tables are supposed to work together is that TableB has a reference to TableA - and it is a 1 to 1 relationship.  TableA however does not have a foreign key to TableB's primary key.

I can obviously set up the following relationships

```
public class TableA
{
    public int TableA_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TableB> TableBs { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int TableB_ID { get; set; }
    public int TableA_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
}
```

With this setup I can say - this and it works ok:

```
TableA.TableBs.FirstOrDefault().SomeField;
```

But, what I really want is this

```
public class TableA
{
    public int TableA_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int TableB_ID { get; set; }
    public int TableA_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
}
```

With this setup I could then say:

```
TableA.TableB.SomeField;
```

Is there any way to map the TableA_ID from TableA to the TableA_ID from TableB to make the TableA class work how I want?

Comment: Entity Framework does not support unique keys, sorry. You could *mostly* get this working by modelling this as `public class TableA { public virtual ICollection<TableB> TableBs { get; set; } }` and making sure never to map more than one `TableB` to the same `TableA`, but you would get stuck with modifications: there is no way to ensure that *during* `SaveChanges`, modifications get sent to the database in the right order, so that's really a non-answer.

Comment: Yes, I have modified my question to reflect this - and that is exactly what I am doing right now.  But, I wanted to stop having to say TableA.TableBs.FirstOrDefault().SomeField; and instead be able to say TableA.TableB.SomeField;

As for the SaveChanges - thats ok - because - for my purposes - I will be accessing this data as read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to preface this answer with the disclaimer that I would not suggest using this solution on a regular basis.  It is not the ideal way I would get this to work - but from a technical standpoint - for my particular situation - it should work out just fine.

Ideally I would really like to have a TableB_ID field in the TableA table.  That would then be an appropriate foreign key to the TableB table - and everything would work out great.

That being said.  Because the TableA_ID field on the TableB table is unique and not null - and - because you are able to specifically tell EF what to use as the primary key and foreign key - I was able to lie to EF and make it use for TableB the TableA_ID field as the primary key.  Because of this - I was then able to tell TableA that its TableA_ID field was a foreign key to my TableB reference and all worked fine.

Here is the fluent API bits I used to tell EF this lie.

In my TableB EntityTypeConfiguration that I instantiate in the OnModelCreating override I say the following.

```
this.HasKey(t => t.TableA_ID);
this.HasRequired(b => b.TableA).WithOptional(a => a.TableB);
```

This puts in the necessary bits to make everything point correctly for my situation.  TableB ends up having a required link to TableA through the TableA_ID columns -and TableA has an optional link to TableB also through the TableA_ID columns.

And, of course, since I have lied to EF and specifically told it that the TableA_ID field of TableB is the primary key - TableB_ID of the TableB table is not marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

On a `one-to-one` relation, EF is going to use the `PK` from Table A (in this case) to be the `PK` for Table B. Your `TableB` class should look like this:

```
public class TableB
{
    public int TableB_ID {get;set;}
    public virtual TableA TableA {get;set;}
}
```

No need to include `TableA_ID` because both `PK` will be the same.

```
builder.Entity<TableA>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.TableB)
    .WithRequired(b => b.TableA)
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct - that works like I want.  What doesn't is public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; } from the class TableA.  And, that is what I'm asking how to get working.

Comment: This maps TableA.TableA_ID to TableB.TableB_ID.  I assume because EF is assuming that you must map a foreign key of TableA (which is in this case TableA.TableA_ID) to the primary key of TableB (which is in this case TableB.TableB_ID).  Which is of course not what. I want TableA.TableA_ID to map to TableB.TableA_ID.

Comment: I was thinking it may be possible to add TableB_ID to TableA - if I were able to modify the SQL that gets ran when EF populates TableA from the database.  Something like this would do the trick.  select a.*, b.TableB_ID from TableA a left outer join TableB b on a.TableA_ID = b.TableA_ID

Comment: @SeanHosey I think this is not doable with EF Code First, you might want to try and look into EF Database First, since you already have the database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx

Comment: This is actually very close - the only thing missing is that you need to lie to EF and tell it that TableB's primary key is really the TableA_ID field and then these pointers you have set up will indeed work correctly.  This is not something I would recommend doing in every situation - but in my case it will work out - since the TableA_ID field of TableB is unique and not null.